# UnsatisfiedDependencyException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am new in Spring boot. I am trying to run Existing project on my local system that is already running on server perfectly. When i am running application, i got exception.

Spring boot Application code:

```
@EnableJpaAuditing(modifyOnCreate = false)
public class EventSetupApplication
{
 public static void main( String[] args )
 {
    SpringApplication.run( EventSetupApplication.class, args );
 }
}
```

[image: package structure]

Repository code:

```
    public interface EventCategoryRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EventCategory, UUID>
{
    @Query( "FROM EventCategory eventCategory WHERE ( UPPER( eventCategory.name ) = UPPER( :name ) AND eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL )" )
    Optional<EventCategory> findByNameIgnoreCase( @Param( "name" ) String name );
}
```

EventCategory class code:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners( AuditingEntityListener.class )
@Table( schema = "eventsetup", name = "event_category" )
@SQLDelete( sql = "UPDATE eventsetup.event_category set ec_deactivated = current_timestamp where ec_id = ?" )
@Where( clause = "ec_deactivated IS NULL" )
public class EventCategory extends LocationDomainObject
{
//....
}
```

Exception Log:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryController' defined in file [D:\abcproject\event-setup\out\production\classes\com\demo\eventsetup\eventcategory\EventCategoryController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventCategoryRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.repository.EventCategoryRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:729) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:192) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1270) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$142/2099541600.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.demo.eventsetup.EventSetupApplication.main(EventSetupApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.CommandLineWrapper.main(CommandLineWrapper.java:65) [idea_rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'eventCategoryRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.repository.EventCategoryRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$142/2099541600.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:721) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'eventCategoryRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.repository.EventCategoryRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$142/2099541600.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.Optional com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.repository.EventCategoryRepository.findByNameIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$673/870357935.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$672/74633729.apply(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport$$Lambda$627/1564588329.get(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: deactivated of: com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory [FROM com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory eventCategory WHERE ( UPPER( eventCategory.name ) = UPPER( :name ) AND eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL )]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:670) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy177.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: deactivated of: com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory [FROM com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory eventCategory WHERE ( UPPER( eventCategory.name ) = UPPER( :name ) AND eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL )]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    ... 91 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: deactivated of: com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.propertyException(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractPropertyMapping.toType(AbstractPropertyMapping.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.toType(AbstractEntityPersister.java:1859) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.getPropertyType(FromElementType.java:393) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.getPropertyType(FromElement.java:512) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.getDataType(DotNode.java:687) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.prepareLhs(DotNode.java:270) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.DotNode.resolve(DotNode.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.resolve(HqlSqlWalker.java:1040) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1290) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4717) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4547) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2138) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2066) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:815) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:609) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
```

I also refer below links but not getting solution:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467771/query-not-working-with-more-than-one-object-in-jpa-error-validation-failed-f),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647630/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-jpql),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817396/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-public-abstract-java-util-list),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822071/no-property-findone-found-for-type-class-user),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874743/error-in-query-repository),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861276/spring-data-using-sort-not-at-the-end),[6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629344/jparepository-count-query-querysyntaxexception-entity-is-not-mapped),[7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657292/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumente),[8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35657292/invocation-of-init-method-failed-nested-exception-is-java-lang-illegalargumente),[9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47807941/error-while-creating-custom-queries-in-spring-boot),[10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43408618/pagination-with-spring-boot-usiing-jpa),[11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586263/i-am-getting-java-lang-illegalstateexception-no-data-type-for-node-while-execu),[12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50485679/spring-jparepository-exeption-with-query-method),[13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40238521/could-not-create-query-metamodel-for-method-public-abstract-java-util-optional),[14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981370/solutionunsatisfieddependencyexception-in-spring-boot),[15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44215765/jpa-jpql-unexpected-token-left-near-line-1),[16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059700/spring-data-query-join-validation-error-validation-failed-for-query-for-me),[17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42942282/getting-the-current-logged-in-user-in-jhipster),[18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215781/spring-boot-jpa-validation-failed-for-query-error-for-jpql),[19](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46564089/spring-data-jpa-tables-joining-by-one-to-one-association),[20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301065/validation-failed-for-query-jparepository),[21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40066880/whats-wrong-with-my-jpql-query),[22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822071/no-property-findone-found-for-type-class-user),[23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816004/missing-dependency-for-method-public-org-codehaus-jettison-json-jsonobject),[24](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174790/validation-failed-for-one-or-more-entities),[25](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369047/protected-abstract-or-public-abstract-method-in-abstract-class)

According to me the error is in Repository code. Please Answer if you know the answer. Thanks

## UPDATE

EventCategoryClass:

```
    @Id
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    @Column(name = "ec_id")
    private UUID id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "ec_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "ec_modified")
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 100)
    @Column(name = "ec_name")
    private String name;
```

Comment: is column name `deactivated` or `ec_deactivated` in your entityclass `EventCategory`?

Comment: @AmitKBist Below is my EventCategory class variables:

`@Id
    @JsonProperty( access = Access.READ_ONLY )
    @Column( name = "ec_id" )
    private UUID id;`

    `@JsonIgnore
    @CreatedDate
    @Column( name = "ec_created", nullable = false, updatable = false )
    private LocalDateTime created;`

    `@JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column( name = "ec_modified" )
    private LocalDateTime modified;`

    `@NotNull
    @Size( min = 1, max = 100 )
    @Column( name = "ec_name" )
    private String name;`

Comment: where is `deactivated` column in this `EventCategoryClass` class which you referring in your Query `eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL` in `EventCategoryRepository` class?

Comment: There is no deactivated column. Please tell me meaning of  eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL

Comment: It seems you have a column `deactivated` in your table, and you query is pulling records only for those rows where column `deactivated` is NULL

Comment: Ok @AmitKBist,
Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: deactivated of: com.demo.eventsetup.eventcategory.domain.EventCategory
```

This is the relevant part of your exception. You have this in your query:

```
eventCategory.deactivated IS NULL
```

Is `deactivated` properly annotated? Your question doesn't include the full `EventCategory` class, so beyond pointing this out, I can't help you narrow down your issue.

Comment: Below is my code:

`@Id
    @JsonProperty( access = Access.READ_ONLY )
    @Column( name = "ec_id" )
    private UUID id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @CreatedDate
    @Column( name = "ec_created", nullable = false, updatable = false )
    private LocalDateTime created;

    @JsonIgnore
    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column( name = "ec_modified" )
    private LocalDateTime modified;

    @NotNull
    @Size( min = 1, max = 100 )
    @Column( name = "ec_name" )
    private String name;`